# All minimal subsets of $(X,G)$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $G$ be the group of homeomorphisms on $X$. I want to find all the minimal subsets of $(X,G)$.
Actually, here $(X,G)$ is a transformation group and a minimal set in this set is a set which is closed and invariant and has no closed and invariant subset...

Comment: at a guess, it might be the two element set $\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment of @RyleeLyman, the only minimal set is $\{0,1\}$.

For the proof, given any $a,b \in (0,1) = [0,1] - \{0,1\}$ there exists $f \in G$ such that $f(a)=b$. Namely, just write down the formula which maps $[0,a]$ onto $[0,b]$, and $[a,1]$ onto $[b,1]$, by affine transformations:
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{b}{a} t & \quad\text{if $t \in [0,a]$} \\
\frac{1-b}{1-a} t - \frac{1-b}{1-a} a + b &\quad\text{if $t \in [a,1]$}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, if a closed invariant subset $S \subset [0,1]$ contains a point of $(0,1)$ then it contains all of $(0,1)$, and since $S$ is closed it follows that $S=[0,1]$.